# Swift - UITableView doesn't work with delegates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

The problem is that `UITableView.dataSource` works fine with extensions, but does not work with delegates.
I created new project and added just one `UITableView` to the storyboard.

Here is the code using extension:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
//        tableView.dataSource = Delegate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
//class Delegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(1) // called several times
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print(2) // called

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        }
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Using delegate:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.dataSource = Delegate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

//extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
class Delegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(1) // called several times
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print(2) // doesn't called

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
        }
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: Your `cellForRowAt` Not called ? Check Height of your tableview

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is called or not  you have mentioned // called several times

Comment: @MikeAlter The answer is already given below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store your `Delegate` object in you view controller. The reason for this is that `dataSource` variable of `UITableView` is a `weak` variable (so as to prevent retain cycles) - it means that if it isn't stored somewhere in a `strong` variable, it will immediately get deallocated.

```
tableView.dataSource = Delegate()
```

Here you assign new instance of `Delegate` to a weak variable and nowhere else. Do something like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate = Delegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self.delegate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dataSource` and `delegate` are both `weak`. So your `Delegate()` object with no strong reference will be released after `viewDidLoad()`.

If you want to use delegate this way, just `var delegate: Delegate!` in your `ViewController`. Then in the `viewDidLoad()` :

```
self.delegate = Delegate()
tableView.delegate = self.delegate
```